# calling variable in functions and global variables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a function that connects to a database and returns some data to display, I have:

```
function viewer ($view_type){  
    if ($view_type=1){
        $query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE the_id='1234'";
        $run= mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die....;
```

Which is called in:

```
include('/../includes/connect.php');
$view= 1;
viewer($view);
```

This is where I get the undefined variable dbc error. The $dbc variable is defined in connect.php which is called in the include(). I realise that the function cannot call the include() variable.

I have done some research and have found that I can call it as a global variable. However I am cautious of this as the dbc variable contains sensitive DB information:

```
$dbc=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

I have also tried adding the include to the function itself however as I need to connect to the DB on the page before calling the function i recieve 'variable DB_HOST already defined' errors.
Would it be appropriate to define $dbc as a global variable? If not how can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's okay:

```
function viewer ($view_type){  
    GLOBAL $dbc; // here is your database connection
    if ($view_type=1){
        $query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE the_id='1234'";
        $run= mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die....;
```

Comment: you don't need to put global $dbc inside the function. outside is much better

Comment: @George, you should read more on [`PHP variables scopes`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Have you even tried what you offer?

Comment: Ups, I tried now. +1 for correct answer. I remember that I used my method but not like in this case , in a function. I am sorry.

Comment: That's okay :-) I've got 5 years of writing `global` keyword behind :))

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your answers that works perfectly. Just wondering are there any security risks associated with setting $dbc as a global variable?

Comment: I don't think so especially since `PHP` is not multi-threaded.

Answer (score 0):

put in your current file (where is called viewer())

```
global $dbc;
```

after including your connect script